# Send additional parameters to social login

Tags: servicestack

Is there anyway to save additional data to the session when doing a social login/signup?

I noticed that if I send `returnUrl` parameter to the SS OAuth endpoint (i.e. `/auth/google?retunUrl=...`) then this value gets saved to the session as `ReferrerUrl` so I am using that to embed data as url parameters.  I would prefer to be able to write to the `Meta` collection when directing to the SS Auth endpoint and then later read it from the session.

I tried to follow the exact process of how this was being saved to the session but I found it quite confusing.

What is the best way to add additional meta data to a social login/signup?

Edit:

I am talking about making a GET request to `/auth/google`, `/auth/facebook` etc...

I have additional data I want to track with the signup the user has entered in the browser.

If I add code to `OnAuthenticated` then this doesn't solve problem as the data has gone out of scope of the browser.  It has to be passed in the GET request to the auth endpoint or have some reference to match up.

Edit:

```
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public override void OnCreated(IRequest httpReq)
    {
        this.Meta.Add("foo", "bar");
        httpReq.SaveSession(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle a callback with the `OnAuthenticated()` [Session or Auth Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#session-events).

Comment: I have data in the client (browser) I want to save (data from a multipart signup process).  I need the `auth/{social provider}` endpoint to save this data to the session ideally to the meta collection.  If I add code to `OnAuthenticated` then how am I reading data from the client?  This has to be passed to the auth service with GET request.  Is there anyway to pass meta data?

Comment: If I could access the session in OnCreated/OnLoad then I could read whatever I wanted from URL or FormData and write it to the session but in the auth events only OnAuthenticated and OnRegistered have the session available.

Comment: (assuming its the same session that is used when the user returns from OAuth, im not sure if that is the case or it makes a new one)

Comment: @Guerrilla You can intercept any Service Request via the [Global Request Filter](https://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters) (e.g. look for Authenticate Request DTO), you can also intercept when sessions are saved in ServiceStack by overriding `OnSaveSession()` in your AppHost. I'd look at using the [Session Bag](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#using-dynamic--untyped-sessions-in-session-bag) for maintaining any pre-auth user state before they're authenticated, which you can read from the OnAuthenticated() event when they do Authenticate from `IRequest.GetSessionBag()`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try request filter.  Is it possible to access the session in `OnCreated` or `OnLoad`?  I tried `var session = httpReq.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();` but it makes the app hang and I get a socket exception.

Comment: @Guerrilla The session factory in your AuthFeature is what’s used to create a new Session instance. Your socket Exception wouldn’t be related, sounds like it’s just not able to connect to your distributed caching provider for an unrelated reason.

Comment: I added the code to my question adding arbitrary value in OnCreated so I would assume then that every session would have this value saved but it doesn't.  Am I referencing/saving it wrong?  (thanks for the help, sorry for all the questions)

Comment: @Guerrilla I’ve nothing else to add from my first comment, the session factory is called each time a session is created but the only time it’s useful is when it’s saved or authenticated, read my comments again for how to intercept.

Comment: It was simpler than it seemed.  I was testing it by writing data into meta dictionary but it seems the autentication service writes an empty collection into meta so I thought it wasn't working.  If I write data to a custom property then it works fine.  Sorry for the confusion I have it working now